# force google to refresh token via python social auth

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, python-social-auth

We're working on a project that depends on PSA (0.2.1) for authentications with google oauth2 (offline). Somehow we lost some refresh tokens of some users, we want to force those users to RE-AUTHENTICATE so we can get new refresh token from google

we tried both :

1. Diconnect those users using /diconnect/google-oauth2, we got a NotAllowedToDisconnect exception, even after removing `social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect` from `SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE`, we got no exception, but when the user re-authenticate, there is no refreh_token in google response
2. add approval_prompt=force to 'account:social:begin' url, but it doesn't return the refresh_token

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

*Update*: We tried to use `{% url 'account:social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?approval_prompt=force&next=/` to force the approval_prompt for certain users (with missing tokens), but its seem to have no effect over google oauth.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this setting does the trick:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'approval_prompt': 'force'
}
```

Use case example at http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#re-prompt-google-oauth2-users-to-refresh-the-refresh-token

Comment: Actually adding {'approval_prompt': 'force'} to ``SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS``, leads to that everytime an existing user wants to login, google will always asks him for offline access, we want only users who lost refresh_token to be asked for this

Comment: But you won't be able to know it until you identify the current user and it's association in the DB.

Comment: You're right, So is there a trick to pass an extra param to PSA, which in its turn, passes this param to the provider an runtime ? that would be great

Comment: If you are able to identify the users that require that parameter, then you can set ``{'approval_prompt': 'auto'}`` and then call ``/login/google-oauth2?approval_prompt=force`` to override that value. Another option would be to use a custom pipeline that will check the lack of ``refresh_token`` and redirect the user to ``backend.auth_url() + "&approval_prompt=force"``

Comment: 1- by setting ``approval_prompt`` to ``auto`` and calling ``/login/google-oauth2?approval_prompt=force`` we got ``OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value``. 2- I think we mentioned above that we already added ``{% url 'account:social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?approval_prompt=force``, in the template for those who lost their ``refresh_token`` which didn't return the refresh_token, but still we did what you asked, by redirecting users to ``backend.auth_url() + "&approval_prompt=force"`` which in its turn didn't return the ``refresh_token``, so the user got stuck in that page

Comment: 1. You mean that by defining the setting in the answer but with ``'auto'`` instead of ``'force'`` and then sending the users to ``/login/google-oauth2/?approval_prompt=force`` you get that "OAuth2 parameters can only have single values"? Just tested, it works, maybe you got that message when doing ``backend.auth_url() + "&approval_prompt=force"``